# How to make Web Worker async?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-worker, worker

The task is: work with large amount of data in the Worker and render the result of the algorithm after each iteration (I render **dataObj** to the HTML). Using following code make web page freezed and slow. How to avoid it?

```js
onmessage = (e) => {
 let number = 0;
 let totalNumbers = 0;
 let primeNumbers = 0;

 if (e.data === "start"){
  while(true){
   totalNumbers++;
   if (isPrime(number)){
    primeNumbers++;
   }
   number++;

   let dataObj = {
    totalNumbers: totalNumbers,
    primeNumbers: primeNumbers
   }

   postMessage(dataObj);
  }
 } else{
  
 }
}

function isPrime(n) {
  if (n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 5 || n == 7) {
    return true;
  } else if ((n < 2) || (n % 2 == 0)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    for (var i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
      if (n % i == 0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be calling postMessage with new data in a tight loop. This can't be light for the browser. A solution could be for example to have the browser's thread querying data every N seconds instead.

Comment: @DenysSéguret you mean calling postMessage every N seconds? not after each iteration, right?

Comment: I was proposing the reverse, having the gui call the web worker, but you might have success the other way too.

Comment: @someserj You probably only want to call `postMessage` once you've found a prime. Your current code is creating a _message_ event on the client for each number.

Comment: Is this the code of the worker? Can you also show the code of the page that "feels slow" (and presumable sends input to the worker and receives results from it)?

Comment: Btw, your attempt at generating primes is *very* slow. Your `isPrime` check should take into account the already found primes - collect them in an array for that - and only try to divide by those